# How do you install podman-remote on Windows?

Tags: podman

I have a windows client which I want to connect to a Linux server.

The linux server already has podman setup.

I see on the user guides that to install podman on windows you need to use the MSI - but I cannot run this as it is blocked by my firm's policies.

Is there a "portable" version of Podman for windows? Or at least just the podman-remote binary - which I can then configure to use the linux server in the backend?